# Seg fault when initializing my queue's head/tail to NULL;

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm having issues solving this segmentation fault. I've been trying to fix this for a few hours, but I've run out of ideas+google searches, so I'm hoping to get some help.

What I have is a queue struct, which keeps track of head & tail nodes which are also structs.

The problem that I'm having is that any interaction with queue_1 is resulting in a segmentation fault.

```
typedef struct customer{
    int id;
    struct customer *next;
}customer_t;

typedef struct customer_queue{
    customer_t *head;
    customer_t *tail;
}queue;

queue *queue_1;



int main(){
    initialize_queue(queue_1); //segmentation fault here.
    customer_t *customer_1 = create_customer(1234); //this section works if we ignore the above line
}

void initialize_queue(queue *q){
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;
}

customer_t *create_customer(int id){
    customer_t *customer = malloc(sizeof(customer_t));
    customer->id = id;
    customer->next = NULL;
    return customer;
}
```

Comment: `queue_1` is NULL at program start so you can't dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

`queue_1` is set to NULL when the program starts as it is an uninitialized variable at file scope.  So when you pass it to `initialize_queue` and subsequently try to set the fields you're dereferencing a NULL pointer.  This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this particular situation causes your code to crash.

You don't need to define `queue_1` as a pointer to a `queue`.  Just define it as a `queue` and initialize it:

```
queue queue_1 = { NULL, NULL};
```

Strictly speaking you don't need to initialize it as both members will get implicitly initialized to NULL, but better to be explicit about it.

Comment: I was hoping to define it as a non-pointer, but then I got confused when trying to pass the queue as a parameter, so I made it a pointer.
So from what I gather after reading the feedback the following are true:
Initializing queue as a non-pointer will initialize the struct's variables to null.
I can still send the address of this non-pointer whenever I want by using '&' in the parameters. This means that even though I don't have a pointer for the queue, I can still use it as if I do have a pointer.
PS: Thanks for the teachings!

Answer (score -2):

```
void initialize_queue(queue *q){
    q = malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;
}
```

your queue is not allocated, to debug easily segmentation fault, use valgrind, it's a memory tracer, in complation add -g3 flag to get the line of the error on the execution, the execution : "valgring ./binary_name"
and compilation: "gcc filename flags "-W -Wall .. -g""

Comment: This leaks memory.

Comment: Not necessarily, but it will in this case once someone attempts to dereference `queue_1` after this function returns.

Comment: Thanks for this! I really wish I understood why malloc is needed in this scenario. 
As far as I can tell, the queue, which contains only 2 variables will never change in size, so why does it need malloc?

Comment: because you use a pointer, if you don't want the pointer declare queue_1 without the pointer "queue queue_1;", and in the function you use the adress of the queue_1 "initialize_queue(&queue_1);"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll take that information to the bank.